# Sequelize where condition for nested models

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a database with notes and users.Now i want to get all notes where note content = something or users.name = something.I can write this query easily with SQL but couldn't get it working with  sequlizer.

```
Note.findAll({
   include: [
             { model: Users, where: { name: 'something' }}
    ]
})
```

expected query is

```
select * from users,notes where notes.content='something' or users.name='something'
```

The issue is Note is not inside include so I cannot use

```
where: {
     '$or':{
```

My question is how to have where with or condition on nested table using sequelize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Note.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            { content: { [Op.like]: 'something' } },
            { '$users.name$': { [Op.like]: 'john' } },
        ]
    },
    include: [
        { model: Users, as: 'users', required: true }
    ]
})
```